# How to make heatmap square in Seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn's `FacetGrid` class to plot a set of matrices using the `heatmap` function, also from Seaborn. However, I cannot adjust the aspect ratio of these subplots. Here is an example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate a set of sample data
np.random.seed(0)
indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((range(5), range(5), range(5)), names=('label0', 'label1', 'label2'))
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=len(indices)), index=indices, columns=('value',)).reset_index()

def draw_heatmap(*args, **kwargs):
    data = kwargs.pop('data')
    d = data.pivot(index=args[1], columns=args[0], values=args[2])
    sns.heatmap(d, **kwargs)

fg = sns.FacetGrid(data, col='label0')
fg.map_dataframe(draw_heatmap, 'label1', 'label2', 'value', cbar=False)
```

That produces this image:

[image: horizontal array of plots]

Notice how the elements of the matrix plots are rectangular, rather than square. If I were making one plot (without the `FacetGrid`), I could pass the option `square=True` to `sns.heatmap` to make the plot square. However, if I put that in the arguments to `map_dataframe`, I get this result:

```
fg = sns.FacetGrid(data, col='label0')
fg.map_dataframe(draw_heatmap, 'label1', 'label2', 'value', cbar=False, square=True)
```

[image: array of plots made with square option]

It looks like the axes are too big for the data, even though the default aspect ratio for the `FacetGrid` is 1. (And explicitly setting `aspect=1` when constructing the `FacetGrid` doesn't help.)

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: you question inadvertently solved my question! (how to make a grid of heatmaps).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you set `aspect` argument of `FacetGrid` not only axis limits but the sizes and positions of axis labels and titles are also took into consideration to calculate proper axis geometry. Therefore heatmaps are rectangles.

To adjust quadratic heatmap and axis you may set corrected axis bounding box position manually with function `set_bbox`.

Another way is a little bit tricky. Function `ax.set_aspect` with the second argument `box_forced` would try to adjust heatmap and axis.
However to completely remove remain gray borders you may hide it by setting axis background color according to figure face color like here:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# Generate a set of sample data
np.random.seed(0)
indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((range(5), range(5), range(5)),
 names=('label0', 'label1', 'label2'))
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=len(indices)),
 index=indices, columns=('value',)).reset_index()

def draw_heatmap(*args, **kwargs):
    data = kwargs.pop('data')
    d = data.pivot(index=args[1], columns=args[0], values=args[2])
    sns.heatmap(d, **kwargs)

fg = sns.FacetGrid(data, col='label0')
fg.map_dataframe(draw_heatmap, 'label1', 'label2', 'value', cbar=False, square = True)
# get figure background color
facecolor=plt.gcf().get_facecolor()
for ax in fg.axes.flat:
    # set aspect of all axis
    ax.set_aspect('equal','box-forced')
    # set background color of axis instance
    ax.set_axis_bgcolor(facecolor)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: old question, but I am still wondering if its possible to display one colorbar for a grid of heatmaps, any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875722/seaborn-facetgrid-place-single-colorbar-after-last-subplot

Comment: I think `'box-forced'` is no longer allowed; it's called `"box"` now

Comment: And ``set_axis_bgcolor`` was replaced by ``set_facecolor``

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [`square=True`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) parameter substituting this in your code:

```
fg.map_dataframe(draw_heatmap, 'label1', 'label2', 'value', cbar=False, square=True)
```